# Discord invite joiner

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

i'm trying to make a discord invite joiner, i tried this, but it is not working, how can i fix it?

and how can i make it pick the link directly from a discord channel and not by the user injecting it manually?

[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEgFvgg7ZPI&t=90s) is a tutorial to find your discord token

All the help will be appreciated :)

```py
import requests

link = input('Discord Invite Link: ')
if len(link) > 6:
    link = link[19:]
apilink = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invite/" + str(link)

print(link)

token = "discord token"
headers={'Authorization': token}
requests.post(apilink, headers=headers)
print("All valid tokens have joined!")
```

Comment: please specify an error message. what exactly is not working?

Comment: on the file, it works correctly, i don't get any errors, but the user does not actually enter the discord server

Comment: yeah, I guess, it does not work correctly though. The post method from requests returns a response object (https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). there you have a property "status_code", which, well, tells you the HTTP status code. With your code, and a valid invite link/id, I get a 404 response (that means, URL not found).   
What's your source on the api link?

Comment: i found that on a forum, like 2 weeks ago, i don't know i can't find it anymore, i just searched.. i don't know if this can be useful..
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#invite-resource

Comment: and this is the main page of the api
https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference

Comment: Yeah but that's a GET request, which simply returns some information about that invite. You tried a POST request, which is not specified in the docs. What's your overall goal with that?

Comment: The goal is to join the server automatically through a script...
as of right now i got the link by inserting it manually but the main project it to grab it from a discord channel

Comment: I don't know if this works (at all), but maybe with that endpoint you're closer to what you search: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you using v6? Use v9. Here is what the updated link should look like: `https://discordapp.com/api/v9/invite/...`

Here is code that will work:

```py
import requests

invite_url = input("Invite: ")
invite_code = invite_url.split("/")[-1]

authorization_token = input("Discord auth token: ")

api_invite_url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/" + invite_code

resp = requests.post(api_invite_url, headers={"Authorization": authorization_token})

if resp.ok:
    print("Success!")
else:
    print("Error:" + resp.status_code, resp.text)
```

And this is kinda not allowed by Discord TOS, please keep that in mind when running this code!

Answer (score 0):

The URL `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invite/` is a [deprecated endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#api-versioning-api-versions), and the current Discord API version is **v9** - not **v6**.

You can just use Chrome DevTools and trace the specific requests your browser makes when joining a guild/server. Try this code, which works fine for me.

```py
import requests

invite_url = input("Enter a Discord invite URL: ")
invite_code = invite_url.split("/")[-1]

authorization_token = input("Enter your Discord authorization token: ")

api_invite_url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/" + invite_code

resp = requests.post(api_invite_url, headers={"Authorization": authorization_token})

if resp.ok:
    print("Successfully joined the server")
else:
    print(resp.status_code, resp.text)
```

Keep in mind that any form of automation like this might be against Discord ToS and could get your accounts flagged and disabled. Discord has many algorithms in place to detect and prevent potential abuse. So run the code with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the JSON data as well.

```
import requests

link = input('Discord Invite Link: ')
if len(link) > 6:
    link = link[19:]
apilink = "https://discordapp.com/api/v9/invite/" + str(link)

token = "discord token"

headers = {
    'Host': 'discord.com',
    'Content-Length': '2',
    'Authorization': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Connection': 'close',
}

data = '{}'

response = requests.post(apilink, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

use v9. v6 is slow.
I do not know the reason. Anyone who knows can explain.